# How Does One Read A File Line-By-Line Without Reading Whole File Into RAM

Tags: java, groovy, file-io, inputstream

I'm attempting to find the most efficient method for reading large files, manipulating the data, and exercising some external function on the output in Java/Groovy.  From what I've read one can accomplish this by using a BufferedReader, Scanner, FileIterator, or using Stream but in every test case thus far my  heap overflows.  I'm not sure if I'm performing sequencing my steps improperly or if this is normal behavior.  Any help determining whether I've done something wrong with my code or have overlooked some other method would be greatly appreciated.  The source file is simply a 1GB csv file called test.csv.

```
package test;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import sftp.SftpConnector;
import sftp.SftpHandler;
import sftp.fileInfo;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@RestController
public class TestController {


private SftpConnector connector;

@Autowired
public TestController(){
    try{
        this.connector = new SftpConnector(this.getProperties());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public Properties getProperties(){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try{
        File propfile = new File("C:\\tmp\\connection2.properties");
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(propfile));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
        System.out.println("Could not find the connection.properties prop file.");
    }catch(IOException IO){
        System.out.println("Could not open the connection.properties file.");
    }
    return prop;
}

@GetMapping(value="/test")
@ResponseBody
public String testConnection(){
    String response = "";
    try{
        this.connector.openSFTPConnection();
        response = "Connection has been opened";
    }catch(Exception ex){
        response = ex.getMessage();
    }finally{
        if( this.connector.getSession().isConnected()){
            try{
                this.connector.closeSFTPConnection();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                response = response + ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}

@GetMapping(value="/testLogger")
@ResponseBody
public String testLogger(){
    String response = "";
    Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Logger.getGlobal().getName());
    try{
        SftpHandler handler = new SftpHandler(this.getProperties());
        LOG.addHandler(handler);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        response = ex.getMessage();
    }
    try{
        LOG.info("Opening the SFTP Channel");
        this.connector.openSFTPConnection();
        LOG.info("Channel is opened.  Getting the list of XML's");
        Collection<fileInfo> files = this.connector.ls("/IB_Test", "*.xml");
        LOG.info("List retrieved.  Downloading each xml file");
        for(fileInfo file: files){
            LOG.info("Downloading " + file.getName());
            this.connector.get("/IB_Test/" + file.getName(), "C:\\tmp\\");
            LOG.info("Downloaded");
        }
        LOG.info("All XML's have been downloaded.");
        response = "All files have been downloaded";
    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOG.severe("Exception thrown:" + ex.getMessage());
        response = ex.getMessage();
    }finally{
        if(this.connector.getSession().isConnected()){
            try{
                LOG.info("Attempting to close the SFTP connection");
                this.connector.closeSFTPConnection();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                LOG.severe("Exception thrown: " + ex.getMessage());
                response = response + ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}

@GetMapping(value="/testScanner")
@ResponseBody public String testScanner(){
    InputStream input = null;
    try{
        input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\tmp\\test.csv"));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }catch(Exception fnf){
        System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
    }
    return "File has completed upload line by line...";
}

@GetMapping(value="/testFilesNIO")
@ResponseBody public String testFilesNIO(){
    String output = "";
    try{
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\test.csv"));
        lines.forEach(
                line ->
                        System.out.println(line)
        );
    }catch( Exception ex){
        output = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return output;
}

@GetMapping(value="/testFilesNIOwBufferedReader")
@ResponseBody public String testFilesNIOwBufferedReader(){
    String output = "";
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\test.csv"));
        reader.lines().skip(1).forEach(
                line -> System.out.println(line)
        );
    }catch( Exception ex){
        output = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return output;
}

@GetMapping(value="/trueBufferedReader")
@ResponseBody public String trueBufferedReader(){
    String output = "";
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\tmp\\test.csv"))),10000000);
        String line ;
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        output = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return output;
}

@GetMapping(value="/lineIterator")
@ResponseBody public String lineIterator(){
    String output = "";
    try{
        LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File("C:\\tmp\\test.csv"));
        try{
            while( it.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(it.nextLine());
            }

        }finally{
            LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        output = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return output;
}
}
```

The expected result is to see each line of the CSV file printed to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in all your tests you are reading file line by line to transfer it to `System.out`

if you need to transfer input stream to output stream you can use this approach and it will be the fastest:

```
yourFile.withInputStream{stream->
    System.out << stream
}
```

Note that `System.out` is quite slow...

Answer (score 1):

```
Charset yourCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(your_file, yourCharset )) {
    String singleLine = null;
    while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(singleLine );
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in Groovy:

```
yourFile.withReader('UTF-8') { r ->
    r.eachLine { line ->
        println line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in my CSV file causing there to be no line feed at the end.  Thus it was ready the whole document as 1 line.

Comment: all of the above functions will work without consuming more than 250MB of heap.  Just fyi.